# redis get list which has key start with

Tags: .net, redis

I set some keys to Redis and keys formated `"userId-barcodeNo"`.

ex:

```
Key : 1-54a5f4, Value : {"Name":"Erkan"}
```

Now i need to get a list which has keys start with "userId".

I can get key list by contain char (*)  -  http://redis.io/commands/KEYS

```
KEYS *UserId*
```

But how can i get items with keys which are start with userId

i need something like this : `Get *UserId*`

In .Net here is my code

```
        using (var ioc = new Ioc())
        {
            var client = ioc.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetClient();
            var key = string.Format("*{0}*", User.Identity.GetUserId());
            var list = client.Get<Coupon>(key);
        }
```

it returns null.

Does redis support this ?

Comment: As you said, redis supports it. (you can use something like `KEYS userId:*`) The question is, whether your c#-library supports it. client.Get(key) seems to be the wrong interface.

Comment: Avoid using **`KEYS`** whenever possible - always prefer its polite cousin `SCAN` (http://redis.io/commands/scan)

Answer (score 2):

You can use MGET to fetch all the keys at once. So you can fetch the keys in one call and than catch the values in another.
http://redis.io/commands/mget

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the solution in .Net ServisStackRedis package.

```
 using (var ioc = new Ioc())
    {
        var client = ioc.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetClient();
        var patern= string.Format("*{0}*", User.Identity.GetUserId());

        var keylist = c.SearchKeys("*" + patern + "*");
        var list = client.GetAll<Coupon>(keylist);
    }
```

First i use SearchKeys method to find items which are fit my patern. it returns a keylist than i can pass keylist to GetAll method.